# docker container storage on localhost

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I do not know how to search my question on the internet... I have following case:

I built a base image from my centos 7 vm. Then I moved it to my ldapserver. On which ldap and phpldapadmin have been already installed. My intention was to dockerize my application. So I created the following Dockerfile:

```
[root@ldapserver ~]# cat /root/ldap_container/dockerfile_ldapserver/Dockerfile
FROM msaka/ldapserver
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install openldap compat-openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers openldap-servers-sql openldap-devel; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install phpldapadmin; yum clean all
COPY phpldapadmin.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpldapadmin.conf
COPY hosts /etc/hosts
COPY openldap /etc/openldap
COPY config.php /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
RUN chown root:apache /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
```

As you see from my base image I install openldap and phpldapadmin also copy some files to make container ready to work. Finally I run my container with:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -itd ldapserver2 httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

I do not have any dedicated volume. From my host VM I can reach phpldapadmin's web interface. I add a new user, test the connection to ldap_client. It's working. Then I stop the container.

Normally, if you create for example a file on your container then stop it you will lost your data unless you commit or allocate a dedicated FS. In my case, when I started again my image (not the stopped container but the image) with following command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -itd ldapserver2 httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

I saw my modification was there. Why ? I was expecting to lost the user that I created from phpldapadmin container. It should not have disappeared because I did not commit ? Does it happen because of the changes were done on application layer ?

And the other weird thing is when I stop my container and start httpd on host machine, I login to phpldapadmin's web interface and I see that same user :)) It's something like changes happened on container affect also my local host.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How were you accessing the container web interface? There were no ports published.

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake I corrected it.

Comment: You're also not running an ldap server inside your container, which would imply you are connecting to an ldap server running outside of your container.

Comment: ah yes... I was thinking to run my openldap on the container but base was running on localhost. So you are right :), I was running only phpldapadmin web interface from container. When i stopped slapd service on localhost, I received access denied error. Thanks and shame on me :))